# Evenly distribute spacious nodes along distance

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to evenly distribute two (or more) nodes along a given distance, cf. the MWE below:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    text node/.style={rectangle, draw}
]
    \small

    \begin{scope}
        \node (aa) at (0,0) {};
        \node (ab) at (14,0) {};
        \node (c) [text node, right=of aa] {This is a rather long node with text};
        \node (d) [text node, right=of c] {Short};  
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-1)}]
        \node (ba) at (0,0) {};
        \node (bb) at (14,0) {};
        \node (c2) [text node] at ($(ba)!0.33!(bb)$) {This is a rather long node with text};
        \node (d2) [text node] at ($(ba)!0.66!(bb)$) {Short};   
    \end{scope}

    \foreach \n in {aa, ab, c, d, ba, bb, c2, d2}
        \draw[red, shift=(\n.center)] plot[mark=x] coordinates{(0,0)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When simply placing the nodes next to each other, they obviously clutter at the right of the distance (first case). So I tried to compute their placement along the distance, but this approach fails due to the different sizes of the nodes (second case). How can I compute the positions of the nodes so that the distance between them and to the sides is equal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer proceeds in stages. If you just want the final code, scroll to the bottom.

---

Proof-of-concept, maybe. Note that nodes always have dimensions, even if they are empty. So your picture is misleading in the sense that you do not show the borders of the nodes between which the other nodes are placed. However, their dimensions must be accounted for if the red marks are intended as the relevant points, since those are not on the borders of the nodes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  text node/.style={rectangle, draw, inner sep=2.5pt},
  spread two/.code n args=6{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\firstwidth{width("#3")}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\secondwidth{width("#5")}%
    \path ($(#6.west)-(#1.east)$) ++(-\firstwidth-\secondwidth-10 pt,0) coordinate (a);
    \node (#2) [text node, anchor=west] at ($(#1.east)+1/3*(a)$) {#3};
    \node (#4) [text node, anchor=east] at ($(#6.west)-1/3*(a)$) {#5};
  },
  ]
  \small
  \node (aa) at (0,0) {};
  \node (ab) at (14,0) {};
  \tikzset{spread two={aa}{c}{This is a rather long node with text}{d}{Short}{ab}}
  \foreach \n in {aa, ab, c, d}
  \draw[red, shift=(\n.center)] plot[mark=x] coordinates{(0,0)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: proof-of-concept]

Probably the `\let` syntax might offer a more convenient approach.

---

## Update

It is possible to somewhat automate this. For example, we can get the value of `inner xsep` rather than needing to hard-code it. (Above, I used `2.5pt`. The default is `.3333em`.)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  text node/.style={rectangle, draw},
  spread two/.code n args=6{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\firstwidth{width("#3")}% 145.58443 pt for testing below (default inner xsep is .3333em)
    \pgfmathsetmacro\secondwidth{width("#5")}% 22.1179 pt
    \path ($(#6.west)-(#1.east)$) ++(-\firstwidth-\secondwidth-4*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},0) coordinate (a);
    \node (#2) [text node, anchor=west] at ($(#1.east)+1/3*(a)$) {#3};
    \node (#4) [text node, anchor=east] at ($(#6.west)-1/3*(a)$) {#5};
  },
  ]
  \small
  \node (aa) at (0,0) {};
  \node (ab) at (14,0) {};
  \tikzset{spread two={aa}{c}{This is a rather long node with text}{d}{Short}{ab}}
  \foreach \n in {aa, ab, c, d}
  \draw[red, shift=(\n.center)] plot[mark=x] coordinates{(0,0)};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

As before, this gives us

[image: auto-find all dimensions]

[It is a little different because this version uses the default `inner xsep` since I didn't tell it otherwise, but that's all.]

Here's a check that it does what we'd expect:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  text node/.style={rectangle, draw},
  spread two/.code n args=6{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\firstwidth{width("#3")}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\secondwidth{width("#5")}%
    \path ($(#6.west)-(#1.east)$) ++(-\firstwidth-\secondwidth-4*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},0) coordinate (a);
    \node (#2) [text node, anchor=west] at ($(#1.east)+1/3*(a)$) {#3};
    \node (#4) [text node, anchor=east] at ($(#6.west)-1/3*(a)$) {#5};
  },
  ]
  \small
  \node (aa) at (0,0) {};
  \node (ab) at (14,0) {};
  \tikzset{spread two={aa}{c}{This is a rather long node with text}{d}{Short}{ab}}
  \foreach \n in {aa, ab, c, d}
  \draw[red, shift=(\n.center)] plot[mark=x] coordinates{(0,0)};
  \node [red, inner sep=0pt] at (a) {a};
  \path ($(ab.west)-(aa.east)$) ++(-167.7pt,0) ++(-1.3333em,0) node [blue,inner sep=0pt] {a};
  \node [blue, inner sep=0pt] at ($(aa.east)+1/3*(a)$) {x};
  \node [blue, inner sep=0pt] at ($(ab.west)-1/3*(a)$) {x};
  \node [blue, inner sep=0pt, xshift=145.58443pt] at ($(aa.east)+1/3*(a)+(.6667em,0)$) {x};
  \node [blue, inner sep=0pt, xshift=145.58443pt] at ($(aa.east)+2/3*(a)+(.6667em,0)$) {x};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which gives us

[image: placement check]

showing the blue marks where we'd expect.

However, the syntax leaves something to be desired. We might, therefore, change our definition of `spread two` to be a little more meaningful. For example,

```
\tikzset{%
  text node/.style={rectangle, draw},
  spread two/.code args={#1 and #2 with contents #3 and #4 between #5 and #6}{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\firstwidth{width("#3")}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\secondwidth{width("#4")}%
    \path ($(#6.west)-(#5.east)$) ++(-\firstwidth-\secondwidth-4*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},0) coordinate (a);
    \node (#1) [text node, anchor=west] at ($(#5.east)+1/3*(a)$) {#3};
    \node (#2) [text node, anchor=east] at ($(#6.west)-1/3*(a)$) {#4};
  },
}
```

Now we can write

```
\begin{tikzpicture}\small
  \node (aa) at (0,0) {};
  \node (ab) at (14,0) {};
  \tikzset{spread two=c and d with contents {This is a rather long node with text} and {Short} between aa and ab}
  \foreach \n in {aa, ab, c, d}
  \draw[red, shift=(\n.center)] plot[mark=x] coordinates{(0,0)};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

to produce

[image: more meaning]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  text node/.style={rectangle, draw},
  spread two/.code n args=6{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\firstwidth{width("#3")}% 145.58443 pt for testing below (default inner xsep is .3333em)
    \pgfmathsetmacro\secondwidth{width("#5")}% 22.1179 pt
    \path ($(#6.west)-(#1.east)$) ++(-\firstwidth-\secondwidth-4*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},0) coordinate (a);
    \node (#2) [text node, anchor=west] at ($(#1.east)+1/3*(a)$) {#3};
    \node (#4) [text node, anchor=east] at ($(#6.west)-1/3*(a)$) {#5};
  },
  ]
  \small
  \node (aa) at (0,0) {};
  \node (ab) at (14,0) {};
  \tikzset{spread two={aa}{c}{This is a rather long node with text}{d}{Short}{ab}}
  \foreach \n in {aa, ab, c, d}
  \draw[red, shift=(\n.center)] plot[mark=x] coordinates{(0,0)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  text node/.style={rectangle, draw},
  spread two/.code n args=6{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\firstwidth{width("#3")}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\secondwidth{width("#5")}%
    \path ($(#6.west)-(#1.east)$) ++(-\firstwidth-\secondwidth-4*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},0) coordinate (a);
    \node (#2) [text node, anchor=west] at ($(#1.east)+1/3*(a)$) {#3};
    \node (#4) [text node, anchor=east] at ($(#6.west)-1/3*(a)$) {#5};
  },
  ]
  \small
  \node (aa) at (0,0) {};
  \node (ab) at (14,0) {};
  \tikzset{spread two={aa}{c}{This is a rather long node with text}{d}{Short}{ab}}
  \foreach \n in {aa, ab, c, d}
  \draw[red, shift=(\n.center)] plot[mark=x] coordinates{(0,0)};
  \node [red, inner sep=0pt] at (a) {a};
  \path ($(ab.west)-(aa.east)$) ++(-167.7pt,0) ++(-1.3333em,0) node [blue,inner sep=0pt] {a};
  \node [blue, inner sep=0pt] at ($(aa.east)+1/3*(a)$) {x};
  \node [blue, inner sep=0pt] at ($(ab.west)-1/3*(a)$) {x};
  \node [blue, inner sep=0pt, xshift=145.58443pt] at ($(aa.east)+1/3*(a)+(.6667em,0)$) {x};
  \node [blue, inner sep=0pt, xshift=145.58443pt] at ($(aa.east)+2/3*(a)+(.6667em,0)$) {x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{%
  text node/.style={rectangle, draw},
  spread two/.code args={#1 and #2 with contents #3 and #4 between #5 and #6}{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\firstwidth{width("#3")}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\secondwidth{width("#4")}%
    \path ($(#6.west)-(#5.east)$) ++(-\firstwidth-\secondwidth-4*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},0) coordinate (a);
    \node (#1) [text node, anchor=west] at ($(#5.east)+1/3*(a)$) {#3};
    \node (#2) [text node, anchor=east] at ($(#6.west)-1/3*(a)$) {#4};
  },
}
\begin{tikzpicture}\small
  \node (aa) at (0,0) {};
  \node (ab) at (14,0) {};
  \tikzset{spread two=c and d with contents {This is a rather long node with text} and {Short} between aa and ab}
  \foreach \n in {aa, ab, c, d}
  \draw[red, shift=(\n.center)] plot[mark=x] coordinates{(0,0)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you subtract 10 pt when calculating `coordinate (a)`?

Comment: @Dux The `inner sep` is `2.5pt` and there are 4 lots of it. Hence `10pt`.

Comment: is there a way to get this value from tikz keys to automate the command a bit?

Comment: @Dux Probably but I wasn't sure quite how to do it. To be honest, I assumed that somebody else would have answered by now. I just intended this answer as a beginning i.e. here's how you can get things in the right places manually. I thought somebody would take that (or use a different method) and provide a convenient macro or something ;).

Comment: However, you must be able to recover the value of `inner sep` from the keys somehow..., mustn't you? I mean, it must be there. At least that should be doable. I'll have a look.

Comment: @Dux Please see updated answer above. I still think its surprising nobody has come up with a fast/obvious/doh! answer to this.... (Surely there must be one?!)

Comment: You went into a lot of details here, thank you a lot! I didn't know about the args syntac before... Great answer!

Comment: @Dux Yes, the args syntax thing is neat. I only found out about it by reading somebody's answer here and said just what you just said, 'I didn't know you could do *that*...'. It *is* in the manual but so much is in the manual and it is just one in that enormous list of key-value syntax things.