# How to align nodes in a layered block diagram in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I want to document layered software architectures and [protocol stacks](https://www.oryx-embedded.com/images/tcp_ip_stack_model.png) using TikZ. Each layer has one or more elements, and there is no strict association between elements that are above each other.
I tried this:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (a1) [draw] { A1 };
    \node (a2) [draw,right of=a1] { A2gq };
    \node (a3) [draw,right of=a2] { A3 };
    \node (b1) [draw,below of=a1] { B1 };
    \node (b2) [draw,right of=b1] { B2 };
    \node (b3) [draw,right of=b2] { B3gq };
    \node (b4) [draw,right of=b3] { B4 };
    \node (c1) [draw,below of=b1] { C1 };
    \node (c2) [draw,right of=c1] { C2gq };
    \node (c3) [draw,right of=c2] { C3 };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which looks terrible - especially since the base lines of the nodes are not aligned (nodes containing g or q are higher):

[image: TikZ diagram]

I would like it to look like this:

[image: Manually painted diagram]

Without having to calculate or guess lots of coordinates manually, in order to not complicate modifying the contents. I especially would like the right borders of the boxes to be aligned in order to get a cleaner look. This would be achieved by expanding nodes in rows that are shorter than the longest one, like words in a "justified" (in opposition to "ragged-left") text.
The diagram will be used in a "beamer" presentation. Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a proposal following the end of section 5.1 of the `pgfmanual`. In addition the `positioning` library is loaded.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={minimum height=7mm,
text depth=0.25ex,draw},node distance=9mm and 3mm]
    \node (a1)  { A1 };
    \node (a2) [right=of a1] { A2gq };
    \node (a3) [right=of a2] { A3 };
    \draw[red] (a1.base -| a1.west) -- (a3.base -| a3.east);
    \node (b1) [below of=a1] { B1 };
    \node (b2) [right=of b1] { B2 };
    \node (b3) [right=of b2] { B3gq };
    \node (b4) [right=of b3] { B4 };
    \draw[red] (b1.base -| b1.west) -- (b4.base -| b4.east);
    \node (c1) [below of=b1] { C1 };
    \node (c2) [right=of c1] { C2gq };
    \node (c3) [right=of c2] { C3 };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The red lines are just for illustration and should be removed of course.

**UPDATE**: Make sure that the outer ends of the rows are aligned. **EDIT**: Unified the positioning syntax, big thanks to @sgmoye!

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={minimum height=7mm,
text depth=0.25ex,draw},node distance=3mm and 3mm]
    \node (b1)  { B1 };
    \node (b2) [right=of b1] { B2 };
    \node (b3) [right=of b2] { B3gq };
    \node (b4) [right=of b3] { B4 };
    \node (a1) [above=of b1] { A1 };
    \node (f1) [inner sep=-\pgflinewidth*0.5pt,fit=(b2.west|-a1.north) (b3.east|-a1.south)]{};
    \node (a3) [above=of b4] { A3 };
    \path (a1) -- (a3) node[midway,draw=none] (a2) { A2gq };
    \node (c1) [below=of b1] { C1 };
    \node (f1) [inner sep=-\pgflinewidth*0.5pt,fit=(b2.west|-c1.north) (b3.east|-c1.south)]{};
    \node (c3) [below=of b4] { C3 };
    \path (c1) -- (c3) node[midway,draw=none] (c2) { C2gq };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: A not so fiddly solution. No packages. Just for fun.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
\fbox{ A1 }\hfill\fbox{ A2gq }\hfill\fbox{ A3 }\\[4mm]
\fbox{ B1 }\hfill\fbox{ B2 }\hfill\fbox{ B2gq }\hfill\fbox{ B4 }\\[4mm]
\fbox{ C1 }\hfill\fbox{ C2gq }\hfill\fbox{ C3 }
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: A bit more seriously: if you wish to combine the nice feature of `\hfill` with Ti*k*Z, then you may want to have a look at this snippet.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{tikzbox}
\newcommand{\tikzbox}[2][]{\stepcounter{tikzbox}
\tikz[remember picture]{\node[draw,minimum height=7mm,
text depth=0.25ex,#1](tikzbox-\thetikzbox){#2};}}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
\tikzbox{A1}\hfill\tikzbox{A2gq}\hfill\tikzbox{A3}\\[4mm]
\tikzbox[alias=pferd]{B1}\hfill\tikzbox[alias=hase]{B2}\hfill\tikzbox{B2gq}\hfill\tikzbox{B4}\\[4mm]
\tikzbox{C1}\hfill\tikzbox{C2gq}\hfill\tikzbox{C3}
\end{minipage}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{%
\draw[thin,red] (tikzbox-1.base) -- (tikzbox-3.base);
\draw[thick,-latex] (pferd) -- (hase);
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The red line is just for illustration, and there is some more serious application as well. The nodes get auto-labeled, but you can give them your own names using `alias`.

Comment: Nice! Wish I'd thought of that!

Comment: Looks a little fiddly. I had hoped that I was just missing something and there would actually be an easy way for that. Well then, thank you!

Comment: @marmot Just a note: nodes `c1` and `c3` are using the old `of=` syntax. Was that intentional? Otherwise, I'm lost in admiration.

Comment: @sgmoye No, it was not. Good catch! Thanks! (I actually agree with the OP that it is fiddly. However, IMHO it is also due to the fact the that the desired output is a bit less common such that the usual tricks like matrix or chains do not apply. The simplest solution would be to use `\fbox`es and `\hfill`s inside a minipage, I think, but this is a Ti*k*Z question, and I do not know if the nodes will get involved into other things like drawing arrows between them. ;-)

Comment: @Erlkoenig I agree with you that it is fiddly, and added a not-so-fiddly Ti*k*Zless solution. If you intend to add arrows between these nodes, this can also be done using Ti*k*Z overlays. To the best of my knowledge there is no equivalent of `\hfill` inside Ti*k*Z. It might, however, be doable to do that, yet if that's what you're after, please ask a new question.

Comment: @marmot Curious you should say that. I have wished before now for stretchable glue-like skip between nodes in Ti*k*Z.

Comment: @sgmoye Sorry, I don't understand. Which statement are you referring to? (The non-Ti*k*Z solution is crying for `\strut`s, I know. ;-)

Comment: @marmot "...there is no equivalent of `\hfill`..." Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @sgmoye To my knowledge there is none. There is, of course, [@cfr's nice code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/294542/121799) but if I am not mistaken, it only works for two nodes. One may generalize it, though, yet I am not aware of any post where this has been done.

Answer (score 8):

I just discovered Ti*k*Z's `execute at begin node` function. Very handy. It is used on pages 79 and 80 of the Ti*k*Z user guide, though I cannot find it discussed there. This essentially does what @marmot proposes but uses a `\strut` to accomplish it.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,execute at begin node=\strut}]
    \node (a1) { A1 };
    \node (a2) [right=of a1] { A2gq };
    \node (a3) [right=of a2] { A3 };
    \node (b1) [below=of a1] { B1 };
    \node (b2) [right=of b1] { B2 };
    \node (b3) [right=of b2] { B3gq };
    \node (b4) [right=of b3] { B4 };
    \node (c1) [below=of b1] { C1 };
    \node (c2) [right=of c1] { C2gq };
    \node (c3) [right=of c2] { C3 };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Aligned nodes.]

## Update

As I am not a fan of excessive markup, that word 'fiddly' got my attention, as did @marmot's non-Ti*k*Z solution (smart!). So I offer this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}    
%% #1 the distance over which nodes are spread;
%% #2 comma-separated list of node contents.
\newcommand{\stretchtowidth}[2]{%
    \begingroup
    \tikzset{every node/.style={draw}}%
    \hbox to #1{%
        \foreach \n in {#2}{\tikz\node{\strut\n};\hfill}\unskip}%
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document} 

\stretchtowidth{1.25in}{A1,A2gq,A3}

\medskip

\stretchtowidth{1.25in}{B1,B2,B3gq,B4}

\medskip

\stretchtowidth{1.25in}{C1,C2gq,C3}

\end{document}
```

[image: New sample.]

Comment: +1 Consider removing the `draw`s in the nodes, you have already taken care of them by saying `every node/.style={draw...`.

Comment: @marmot Quite right! Was on my to-do list when I noticed the addtional OP requirement to distribute the nodes to a given width. I got distracted... Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: I also removed a spurious `on grid`. And used the `positioning` library.

Comment: Yes, and I updated such that the outer ends are aligned, a requirement that seems to have been ignored by all three of us. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

A solution using the `chains` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        start chain=A going right,
        start chain=B going right,
        start chain=C going right,
        outer sep=0pt,
        inner sep=.2em,
        node distance=1.6em and .25em,
        every node/.style={draw, anchor=base, text height=0.8em, text depth=0.25ex}]
        \node (a1) [on chain=A] {A1};
        \node [on chain=A] {A2gq};
        \node [on chain=A] {A3};
        \node (b1) [on chain=B, below of=a1] {B1};
        \node [on chain=B] {B2};
        \node [on chain=B] {B3gq};
        \node [on chain=B] {B4};
        \node [on chain=C, below of=b1] {C1};
        \node [on chain=C] {C2gq};
        \node [on chain=C] {C3};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but how to make sure that the chains have equal length, i.e. expand nodes in chains that are smaller than the longest chain - a little like "justified" (in opposition to ragged-left) text?

Comment: Whoops I missed that point… I've got to think about it.

Answer (score 3):

When these distributions are more o less regular, you can use a `tcbposter` (from `tcolorbox`). Following code tries to mimmic linked protocol stack with a `tcbposter`. I've supposed a 8 columns x 9 rows distribution where right most column is two column wide. As first 8 rows show a regular distribution it has been easy to place all boxes.

For the 9th row I used `width` tcolorbox option instead of `span` to define the correct width after solving following equation for `\mylength`

`5*\mylength+4*\tcbpostercolspacing = 6*\tcbpostercolwidth + 5*\tcbpostercolspacing`

After that, placement of boxes are fixed with `xshift`.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{geometry}

\standaloneenv{tcbposter}

%\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcbposter}[%
    poster = {columns=8, rows=9, width=17cm, height=8cm, spacing=1mm},% showframe},
    boxes = {colback=cyan!80!black, 
        boxrule=0pt, arc=2mm,
        colframe=cyan!80!black, 
        halign=center, valign=center,   
        colupper=white,
        fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries, size=small}
]
%1st row
\posterbox{column=1, row=1}{HTTP}
\posterbox{column=2, row=1}{HTTP/2}
\posterbox{column=3, row=1}{MQTT}
\posterbox{column=4, row=1}{CoAP}
\posterbox{column=5, row=1}{FTP}
\posterbox{column=6, row=1}{TFTP}

%2nd row
\posterbox{column=1, row=2}{SMTP}
\posterbox{column=2, row=2}{SNTP}
\posterbox{column=3, row=2}{DNS}
\posterbox{column=4, row=2}{NetBIOS}
\posterbox{column=5, row=2, span=2}{SNMPv1/v2c/v3}

%3rd row
\posterbox{column=1, row=3, span=2}{WebSocket}
\posterbox{column=3, row=3}{mDNS}
\posterbox{column=4, row=3}{DNS-SD}
\posterbox{column=5, row=3}{DHCP}
\posterbox{column=6, row=3}{DHCPv6}

%4th row
\posterbox{column=1, row=4,span=6}{Socket}

%5th row
\posterbox{column=1, row=5, span=2.5}{TCP}
\posterbox{column*=5, row=5, span=2.5}{UDP}
\posterbox{column=6, row=5}{RAW}

%6th row
\posterbox{column=1, row=6, span=3}{IPv4}
\posterbox{column=4, row=6, span=3}{IPv6}

%7th row
\posterbox{column=1, row=7, span=1.5}{ARP}
\posterbox{column*=3, row=7, span=1.5}{Auto-IP}
\posterbox{column=4, row=7, span=1.5}{NDP}
\posterbox{column*=6, row=7, span=1.5}{SLAAC}

%8th row
\posterbox{column=1, row=8, span=1.5}{ICMP}
\posterbox{column*=3, row=8, span=1.5}{IGMPv2}
\posterbox{column=4, row=8, span=1.5}{ICMPv6}
\posterbox{column*=6, row=8, span=1.5}{MLDv1}

%9th row
%5 boxes and 4 separations should use 
%equivalent to 6 original boxes plus 5 
%separations 
\newlength{\mylength}
\pgfmathsetlength{\mylength}{(6*\tcbpostercolwidth+\tcbpostercolspacing)/5}%

%Use `width` instead of `span` to fix box size
\posterbox[width=\mylength]{name=91, column=1, row=9}{Ethernet}
\posterbox[width=\mylength]{name=92, column=1, row=9, xshift=\mylength+\tcbpostercolspacing}{Wi-Fi}
\posterbox[width=\mylength]{name=92, column=1, row=9, xshift=2*\mylength+2*\tcbpostercolspacing}{PPP}
\posterbox[width=\mylength]{name=92, column=1, row=9, xshift=3*\mylength+3*\tcbpostercolspacing}{USB/RNDIS}
\posterbox[width=\mylength]{column*=6, row=9}{G3-PLC}

%Right column
\posterbox[colback=gray, colframe=gray, colupper=black]{column=7, row=1, span=2, rowspan=3}{7 - Application}
\posterbox[colback=gray!80, colframe=gray!80, colupper=black]{column=7, row=4, span=2}{5 - Session}
\posterbox[colback=gray!60, colframe=gray!60, colupper=black]{column=7, row=5, span=2}{4 - Transport}
\posterbox[colback=gray!40, colframe=gray!40, colupper=black]{column=7, row=6, span=2, rowspan=3}{3 - Network}
\posterbox[colback=gray!20, colframe=gray!20, colupper=black]{column=7, row=9, span=2}{2 - Data Link}

\end{tcbposter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent example, solved all my problems aside for one short search for "posterbox rowspan"

Answer (score 1):

Thank to @Ignasi who pointed out the `tcolorbox` package, here is another solution with the `raster` functionality.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most, raster}

\begin{document}
    \tcbset{size=small, colframe=red!50!black, colback=red!10!white, raster equal height=rows ,halign=center, valign=center}
    \begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=3]
        \tcbitem A1
        \tcbitem A2gq
        \tcbitem A3
    \end{tcbitemize}
    \begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=4, colframe=blue!50!black, colback=blue!10!white]
        \tcbitem B1
        \tcbitem B2
        \tcbitem B3gq
        \tcbitem B4
    \end{tcbitemize}
    \begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=3]
        \tcbitem C1
        \tcbitem C2gq
        \tcbitem C3
    \end{tcbitemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]