# In tikzposter how to align blocks?

Tags: beamer, block, tikzposter

I want to arrange blocks in the following manner:

[image]

Basically none of the blocks are aligned in a single column or row.
Number of blocks does not matter. I just want blocks to cross over the column or row.
Any idea would be helpful.

Thank You.

Comment: So you are expecting someone else to set up a tikzposter from scratch, post the code and result, and hope that it pleases you? Wouldn't it be much better if you took the first step and provided us with a code that can be used as a basis for answers?

Comment: Well, I am not going to write a poster template for you either. Using tikzposter might not be the easiest way for you to achieve what you want. How a bort using just Tikz and minipages. However, if you really need the tikzposter: You could look at `bodyoffsetx` `bodywidthscale` which are listen in the options for a block in the tikzposter documentation.

Comment: I agree with the others. How about the number of rows and cols? Do you expect the same output? What is your MWE (Minimum Working Example)?

Comment: why not use tikz trees

Comment: This can be done with `tcbposter` (from `tcolorbox`). Later on I'll try to show it, but you can start looking at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447475/1952)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to `tikzposter` could be `tcbposter` part of [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package. It uses a regular scheme (rows and columns) to place boxes, but it's flexible enough to adjust boxes widths and heights. Even box placement and size can be relative to other boxes.

Something similar to OPs scheme could be:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[poster]{tcolorbox}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}[
coverage = {spread, interior style={blue!20}},
poster = {
    %showframe,
    columns=2,rows=7},
boxes = {enhanced, colback=white, colframe=brown, valign=center, halign=center}
]
\posterbox[colback=brown!70!black]{name=title, column=1, span=2, below=top, rowspan=1}{Poster title}
\posterbox{name=box1, column=1, row=2, rowspan=2, span=1.2}{Box 1}
\posterbox{name=box2, column*=2, row=2, span=.8}{Box 2}
\posterbox{name=box3, column*=2, row=3, span=.8}{Box 3}
\posterbox{name=box4, column=1, row=4, rowspan=.9, span=.8}{Box 4}
\posterbox{name=box5, column*=2, row=4, rowspan=1.1, span=1.2}{Box 5}
\posterbox{name=box6, column=1, below=box4, rowspan=.9, span=.8}{Box 6}
\posterbox{name=box7, column*=2, below=box5, rowspan=1.1, span=1.2}{Box 7}
\posterbox{name=box10, column=1, above=bottom, span=1.2, rowspan=1}{Box10}
\posterbox{name=box11, column*=2, above=bottom, span=.8, rowspan=1}{Box11}
\posterbox{name=box8, column=1, between=box6 and box10, span=.8}{Box 8}
\posterbox{name=box9, column*=2, between=box7 and box11, span=1.2}{Box 9}
\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the example. It helped a lot.