# How to remove vertical space between two lines of tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I'd like to make a table-like grid with `tcolorbox` as shown in the following MWE.

Yet the vertical space between two lines of tcolorbox annoys me.

How to remove this space?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}

\begin{document}
\noindent\parindent=0pt

\newtcolorbox{MRS}[2][]{%
  nobeforeafter,sharp corners,
  equal height group=A,
  width=#2,#1
}

\begin{MRS}{3cm}box1 on first line\end{MRS}%
\begin{MRS}{3cm}box2 on first line\end{MRS}\\
\begin{MRS}{6cm}box3 on second line\end{MRS}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

although I don't understand why not use a simple `tabular`, here you have two possible solutions:

Change the space between lines with `\\[-1mm]` (you have to find the correct value)

Build the table with a `tcbraster`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}

\begin{document}
\noindent\parindent=0pt

\newtcolorbox{MRS}[2][]{%
  nobeforeafter,sharp corners,
  equal height group=A,
  width=#2,#1
}

\begin{MRS}{3cm}box1 on first line\end{MRS}%
\begin{MRS}{3cm}box2 on first line\end{MRS}\\[-1.5mm]
\begin{MRS}{6cm}box3 on second line\end{MRS}%


\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=2, raster row skip=-.5mm, raster column skip=-.5mm, raster equal height=rows, raster width=6cm, sharp corners]
\tcbitem Box1 on first line
\tcbitem Box2 on first line
\tcbitem[raster multicolumn=2] Box3 on second line
\end{tcbitemize} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As my real table is complex, it's a bit difficult for `tcbraster` to achieve it. So what causes the vertical space? And how to get the space size? Is there a better way to get the space size more correctly?

Comment: @lyl About the space, take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194427/unwanted-vertical-separation-between-tcolorboxes And about the table format and complexity, why don't you show it? This way we can suggest better options. As an example, with a `tcbposter` you can do something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447475/1952